# How to load data in Zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper

If I use Zookeeper for external application configuration, what is the right way to load the data in Zookeeper the first time, before the application starts? Compare it with loading initial static data to a database, e.g. a list of countries, before starting the application that needs this data. For databases, there are countless ways and tools to do this - slq insert scripts, mongodbimport, liquibase... Zookeeper is not a database, but there should be a way to put some data into it without scripting every step with zkCli.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What you mean is that `you want to use zookeeper to load configuration of another application when that application starts?`. Am I correct?

Comment: Imesha, I added more text to clarify the question. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Zookeeper has a java client. You can use it. But there is `Apache Curator` which is written around Zookeeper java client. You can use that to store and retrieve data in a zookeeper ensemble. Read this blog post by me [Curator in 5 minutes](https://loneidealist.wordpress.com/2016/11/11/488/)

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I use Curator in the application. Still, I wonder how to load some data with a tool, without writing code.

Comment: I've got a similar/related problem: I'd like to use zookeeper as a distributed configuration service in a Spring Cloud application replacing Spring Cloud Config service. The latter service can be backed by a git folder containing a number of properties files whose contents are loaded from the config service at startup and fed to the client applications. It would be nice to have something similar with Zookeeper. Yes, you could write your own java service with the Curator API, but being this a common problem I wonder if there isn't some ready made solution.